# How can export large rasters as Export.image.toDrive in gogole earth engine without spliting the file to many tiles in google drive

Tags: export, large-files, google-earth-engine

I want to export a raster product from google earth engine to google drive by Export.image.toDrive command. because the file is large, the output will appear in google drive as too many files [tiles] (for example: 240 files). When I download them az a zip file, the output doesn't look well. Is there any solution or command to make it possible export it as a single file? my code is as below:

```js
Export.image.toDrive({
 image: AOIclip,
 description:'KhR_Luse_GEE',
 folder:'AOI_GEELAyers',
 //region:table,
 scale: 10,
 maxPixels:1e13,
 skipEmptyTiles: true,
});
```